# How do I add a value for a <textarea> using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I want to add content in a textarea while parsing HTML using Nokogiri:

```
<textarea placeholder="Describe" title="Describe" name="Describe" value=""></textarea>
```

Here is my code where I set the value for the textarea:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML( html_content )
textareas = doc.xpath("//textarea")

textareas.each do |r|
   r.set_attribute("value","Its my content")          
end
```

Here is the output:

```
<textarea placeholder="Describe" title="Describe" name="Describe" value="Its my content"></textarea>
```

I want output like this:

```
<textarea placeholder="Describe" title="Describe" name="Describe" value=""> Its my content </textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML( html_content )
    textareas = doc.xpath("//textarea")

    textareas.each do |r|
       r.content = "Its my content"
    end
```